# Unable to resolve module `metro/src/lib/bundle-modules/HMRClient`

Tags: react-native

I just upgraded from RN 0.55.4 to 0.59.3.....now Im getting following error:

Error: Unable to resolve module metro/src/lib/bundle-modules/HMRClient from ....\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Utilities\HMRClient.js: Module metro/src/lib/bundle-modules/HMRClient does not exist in the Haste module map

The HMRClient.js file does include the following require statement:  `const MetroHMRClient = require('metro/src/lib/bundle-modules/HMRClient');`.....and I cant see that path beginning with 'metro' anywhere so I guess I need to add it somehow.  There is also another require statement as follows: `const invariant = require('invariant');` ....no file name 'invariant' exists either.

Facebook say this was fixed back in 0.53.0 master but looks like its back
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/17742

Below is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "xs",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest",
    "flow": "flow",
    "flow start": "flow start",
    "flow stop": "flow stop",
    "flow status": "flow status",
    "flow coverage": "flow coverage"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^5.11.1",
    "flow": "^0.2.3",
    "flow-bin": "^0.65.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.1",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "0.59.3",
    "react-native-elements": "^0.19.0",
    "react-native-google-places-autocomplete": "^1.3.9",
    "react-native-maps": "git://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps.git#master",
    "react-native-switch": "^1.4.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.5.0",
    "react-navigation": "^2.5.5",
    "react-redux": "^5.1.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^8.2.6",
    "babel-preset-flow": "^6.23.0",
    "eslint": "^4.9.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^16.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.17.3",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.13.0",
    "prettier-eslint": "^8.8.2",
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.3",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.4.3",
    "babel-jest": "^24.7.1",
    "jest": "^24.7.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.53.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Please help!

p.s. the below suggestion does not work

To resolve try the following:
  1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.
  2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.
  3. Reset Metro Bundler cache: `rm -rf /tmp/metro-bundler-cache-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`.
  4. Remove haste cache: `rm -rf /tmp/haste-map-react-native-packager-*`.

Comment: can you go to your `node modules` folder and check if `HMRClient.js`really exists in the mentioned directory?

Comment: Yes its definitely there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pay attention when running `npm install` to see if there is any need for a specific version of something.

First check babel config files then if it doesn't work try the changes in `package.json`.

**Try config files and deps as below**.
This is a config that worked for me for an update from 0.54 to 0.59.5:

package.json:

```
  " dependencies": {
         "react": "16.8.3",
         "react-native": "0.59.5",
         // ...
  },

  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0-0",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.53.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.6.3",
    // ...
  }
```

babel.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
};
```

.babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": ["module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"]
}
```

The only useful info I could find in the RN release notes about babel and metro changes was at [0.57] here:

https://github.com/react-native-community/releases/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

UPDATE NOTE:

**Trying config files as the ones from a new working project (created with 0.59.9) doesn't seem to work for an update from 0.54 to 0.59**

babel.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
};
```

metro.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  transformer: {
    getTransformOptions: async () => ({
      transform: {
        experimentalImportSupport: false,
        inlineRequires: false,
      },
    }),
  },
};
```

and no `.babelrc` file.

*package.json:*

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.5",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.4.5",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.54.1",
  },
```

Comment: tried option 1 didnt work.....tried option 2 didnt work....then upgraded to 0.59.5 to match yours and it worked!!  So happy...thanks very much.  If you give me your email address I can interac the money to you

Comment: I am happy it worked. You don't have to send me any money. You can use 20$ to celebrate you solved the problem ;) In my opinion, upgrading RN still requires courage and patience :) . Congratulations for not giving up!

Comment: @jamesmurphy I updated my answer according to your feedback

Comment: This resolved my case (Expo project): https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/issues/540