# react-native run-android command failed

Tags: react-native

**>  bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module

> `metro/src/lib/bundle-modules/HMRClient` from
>   `D:\korero_latest_app\korero_app\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Utilities\HMRClient.js`:
>   Module `metro/src/lib/bundle-modules/HMRClient` does not exist in the
>   Haste module map
>
> This might be related to
>   https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968 To resolve try
>   the following:
>     1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.
>     2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.
>     3. Reset Metro Bundler cache: `rm -rf /tmp/metro-bundler-cache-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`.
>     4. Remove haste cache: `rm -rf /tmp/haste-map-react-native-packager-*`.
>       at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (D:\korero_latest_app\korero_app\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ModuleResolution.js:183:15)
>       at ResolutionRequest.resolveDependency (D:\korero_latest_app\korero_app\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ResolutionRequest.js:52:18)
>       at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (D:\korero_latest_app\korero_app\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:283:16)
>       at Object.resolve (D:\korero_latest_app\korero_app\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\node_modules\metro\src\lib\transformHelpers.js:261:42)
>       at dependencies.map.result (D:\korero_latest_app\korero_app\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:399:31)
>       at Array.map ()
>       at resolveDependencies (D:\korero_latest_app\korero_app\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:396:18)
>       at D:\korero_latest_app\korero_app\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:269:33
>       at Generator.next ()
>       at asyncGeneratorStep (D:\korero_latest_app\korero_app\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:87:24)
>   DELTA  [android, dev] ./index.js ▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓░░░░ 76.0% (930/1067),
>   failed.
>
> ::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [03/Feb/2020:08:51:14 +0000] "GET
>   /index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false HTTP/1.1" 500 -
>   "-" "okhttp/3.12.1"**
>
> package.json:-

```
{
  "name": "korero_app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "formik": "^1.5.7",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "0.59.9",
    "react-native-action-button": "^2.8.5",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-floating-action": "^1.17.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-material-textfield": "^0.12.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^2.7.3",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.5.0",
    "react-navigation": "^3.11.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "reselect": "^4.0.0",
    "styled-components": "^4.3.1",
    "tls": "0.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.4.5",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.4.5",
    "babel-jest": "24.8.0",
    "jest": "24.8.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.54.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

> bable.config.js

```
    module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
};
```

**metro.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  transformer: {
    getTransformOptions: async () => ({
      transform: {
        experimentalImportSupport: false,
        inlineRequires: false,
      },
    }),
  },
};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to resolve module \`metro/src/lib/bundle-modules/HMRClient\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56764812/unable-to-resolve-module-metro-src-lib-bundle-modules-hmrclient)

Comment: Can you post your ```package.json``` file?

Comment: try this ``del %appdata%\Temp\react-native-* & cd android & gradlew clean & cd .. & del node_modules/ & npm cache clean --force & npm install & npm start -- --reset-cache``

Answer (score 1):

Resolve building modules:

1. Delete the node_modules
2. yarn install
3. yarn add jetifier
4. yarn run jetify
5. rebuild project in android studio

Happy coding :)